# Generating a taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a list of items that I need turned into a taxonomy. My list looks something like this:

```
Apple
    Apple 1a
    Apple 1b
    Apple 2a
    Apple 2b
    ...
    Apple 192b
Banana
    Banana 1a
    Banana 1b
    Banana 2a
    Banana 2b
    ...
    Banana 96a
....
More Items
    More Items 1a
    ....
    More Items 300b
```

Anyway you get the idea. Creating new terms for each of these isn't going to work in this case , it'll take days. Is there any way to bulk create from a text file like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get your terms into CSV format you can use the excellent [Taxonomy CSV import/export](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) module:

> This module allows you to import or export taxonomy from or to a CSV (comma-separated values) file or with a copy-and-paste text.

It has support for importing hierarchical trees like yours, and even supports drush.

It also has [good documentation](http://drupalcode.org/project/taxonomy_csv.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/taxonomy_csv.help.html) to get you started.

**EDIT**

You could also try the [Taxonomy import/export via XML](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_xml) module which does the same thing but for XML (if you find it easier to get your data into that format). It's only in dev release at the moment but its worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the Feeds module as it allow syou to both upload a file and create taxonomy terms based on the input. It is a little more configurable and as a result powerful but might be a little more difficult to setup.

If CSV gets the job done easily for you go with it otherwise i KNOW feeds can intelligently do what you need. Espercially if you combine it with feeds_tamper and a custom parser form contrib.